# Firebase & Swift: Does not download Video to URL

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, directory

I want to download Videos from Firebase Storage into my App directory.
I´m using the following code:

```
 func downloadVideo(message: Message){
    guard let videoURL = message.videoURL else {return}
    if let localURL = setupURL(url: videoURL){
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: localURL)
        let filePath = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: videoURL)
        filePath.write(toFile: url, completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("ERROR WHILE DOWNLOADING THE VIDEO:", error as Any)
            }else{
                print("Video Saved to URL:", url as Any)
            }
        })
    }
}

func setupURL(url: String) -> String?{
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileName = (url as NSString).lastPathComponent
    let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/\(fileName)"
    if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: filePath) == true{
        return nil
    }else{
        return filePath
    }
}
```

However, I can´t open it via the app and the terminal says that the File does not exist. The path is available though.

How can this problem be solved?

Best regards

EDIT:

The download seems to get completed since it prints out "Video saved to URL:" ...

In the terminal I can find the path of the video but trying to open it, the terminal logs that the file does not exist.

Comment: You need to look at the permissions. It sounds like the authentication is failing or indeed you simply don't have permission to access the link.

Comment: Thank´s for the answer! I just edited the question and think that there must be a different error since the download completes.